# Nginx: $request_time not being logged

Tags: nginx

This is my log_format in **nginx**

```
   log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
             '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
             ' $request_time';
```

And here is the output of the access log

```
x.x.155.x - - [31/Oct/2011:03:54:18 +0000] "POST /xx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 127 "http://xx/ab.cc" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
```

Somehow the request time is **not getting logged**. Can someone help figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you haven't specified the `main` as format for `access_log`:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
```

so the `combined` format is used.